# Firestore instantiate objects with data recover Swift 5.0

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, instantiation

I get all the data from my snapshot and create an object list with the data.
My problem: I can't return a list to use my objects in other code functions.

I tried to browse my list to create using my snapshot to implement a new list of objects declared above in my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var usersCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("ship")
var ships: [MyShip] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getUsers()
   print(ships.count)


}
```

The getData function:

```
 func getUsers() {
    usersCollection.getDocuments { (snapshot, _) in

       //let documents = snapshot!.documents
       //  try! documents.forEach { document in

       //let myUser: MyUser = try document.decoded()
       //print(myUser)
        //}

        let myShip: [MyShip] = try! snapshot!.decoded()

        // myShip.forEach({print($0)})


        for elt in myShip {
           print(elt)
            self.ships.append(elt)
        }
        print(self.ships[1].nlloyds)
    }
}
```

[result console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmEpN.png)

Result in the console:

```
- my list is not filled return 0
- I print the objects well and I print them well
- I print the ships object[1].nloyds = 555 well in the function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print(ships.count)` call in `viewDidLoad` is printing an empty array because the `.getDocuments()` method is asynchronous. Try writing `getUsers` as a closure like this:

```
func getUsers(completion: @escaping ([MyShip]) -> Void) {
    usersCollection.getDocuments { (snapshot, _) in
        let myShip: [MyShip] = try! snapshot!.decoded()
        completion(myShip)
    }
}
```

and then use it in the `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getUsers() { shipsFound in
        self.ships = shipsFound
        print(self.ships.count)
    }

}
```

Comment: I thank you your solution works to display ships.
but I would have liked to manipulate them a little like I do in my listView 
an example in pictures : (https://imgur.com/a/iPfowPq)  , if you have sites with sample codes to learn how to use Firestore I am very interested! :)

Comment: You should still be able to manipulate the data, you just have to make sure you have it first. Put `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside the closure after `self.ships = shipsFound` so the tableView loads the results of the closure method. Also if my original answer solved your initial question, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Comment: Also I just read Firebase's documentation, it's super thorough, you should check it out if you haven't already! https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: thank you for all of you ,I validated your answer !